# By selenium IDE with the help of javascript , how can i log test result in MS XL or CSV file

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

Currently i'm working on selenium IDE,every time with for same test cases i have to copy the test result from log into xl file ...is there any other way by using any predefined js file of selenium i can write the test result log in MS XL or CSV file

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin you can get called [File Logging](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/file-logging-selenium-ide/) which records the log output in an external file. It's not an excel document, but it may be a start for what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>LOG.entries.toSource()</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${x}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Which will print out the contents of the entries object. At that point you should be able to do typical javascript functions with it. But I think javascript has some limitations on saving files so you'll have to work around that.